# Can't save reports

Tags: civireport, reports

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.11 on Drupal. For some time now (not sure how many minor versions) it has not been possible to create reports or to save changes to any reports. The button ("Update Report", I believe it used to say) is missing.

This is the case on my live and dev sites. On the dev site I disabled all extensions which did not help. I can't check on demo.civicrm.org as it is currently broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually no problem with saving reports, it's just that the UI has changed, and you now need to pick "Save" from the "Actions" menu.

Comment: In my case, save is not in the Actions menu, even after clearing caches, emptying the `templates_c` folder and making a change and refreshing results. v. 5.23.3

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue - only to discover after a bit of digging that a new CMS acl persission "save Report Criteria" - was added in later version of civi and I didnt grant that to the user.

Hope this helps

Comment: This was helpful thank you. I found the needed permission under the CiviCRM permissions within Drupal.

Comment: However, after adding those permissions and logging out and back in, I still don't see save option in actions menu.